# MySQL Sorting By Top 10

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the midst of creating a workout log for a team of mine. What I currently have is a MySQL query (written in PHP) that retrieves an array of user ids associated with posts made in the current week. The code is as follows:

```
mysql_query("SELECT u_id FROM posts WHERE id IN (SELECT p_id FROM post_groups WHERE g_id='" . $group['id']. "') AND date >= '" . $d_start . "' AND date <= '" . $d_end . "'");
```

To better explain this, say a user with `u_id = 6` posts five workouts this week. The array generated by the above query should contain `6` a total of five times. This is done for every workout posted by users in the week - so I end up with a large array full of duplicate user ids.

What I am looking to do is, instead, return an array of size 10 that contains the `u_id`s that appear most frequently in the array above. So, if `u_id = 6` appeared the most frequently in the above array, let's say 10 times, and `u_id = 8` appeared the second most frequently, let's say 9 times, then the array that I wish to return would have a value of `6` at [0] and a value of `8` at [1], etc.

I am not sure how to trim down this array and sort it by most frequent occurrences of `u_id`, as my SQL skills are a little lacking at this moment. I was hoping someone would be able to shed some light on the ideal query that I am looking for. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use both `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, and `TOP`.

`GROUP BY` will group your results by a particular field, in this case you want to be grouping by u_id.

```
GROUP BY u_id
```

`ORDER BY` lets you order your resultset. In this example you want to group by the `COUNT()` of how many rows each user has. We also use the `DESC` keyword to order them in descending order (highest to lowest).

```
ORDER BY COUNT(u_id) DESC
```

`TOP` lets you only get the top X results. In the example below only the top 10 rows will be returned.

```
TOP 10
```

So putting it all together, to group by user id, order by the count of each userid in descending order and to limit the results to 10:

```
SELECT u_id 
FROM posts 
WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT p_id 
   FROM post_groups 
   WHERE g_id='" . $group['id']. "') 
AND date >= '" . $d_start . "' 
AND date <= '" . $d_end . "'
GROUP BY u_id
ORDER BY COUNT(u_id) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**On a side note...** you [really shouldn't be using the mysql_* functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) (meaning they'll be removed in a future version of PHP). Instead look into using prepared statements with either [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

There are plent of good examples of [using PDO here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers), and here on using [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: Thank you very much! The format of your answer was very neat and helpful - it definitely helped me to figure out exactly where the lapse in my thinking was. As for MySQLi, I am planning on transitioning to that - I just figured I'd get this done with what I am most familiar with first - but the advice will definitely be taken. Regards.